# mysql database visualization software for windows 7

Tags: windows, data-visualization, mysql

I Am looking for a open source windows 7 application for visualizing my mysql database.

I have a sql file (more than 250MB) which have query to create database, which i should load in the application and database schema should be displayed in graphical or pictorial representation.
As this file is huge i cannot upload on internet, so i am looking for windows application.

Are there any applications for this?

Comment: Navicat is the best I used so far

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of these, and G.I.Y.F. But, what's wrong with the classic [MySql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)?

In addition to allowing you to graphically create a new data base schema (and generate code to create it), it will import from an existing database and allow you to examine it's structure.

This is the standard tool for all MySql manipulation, from the developers of MySql itself. I have tried others, but always come back to this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i am using Mysql Workbench 6.3.6 and i connected to a database but iam not able to get ER diagram of that database . Could you tell me how to get it. +1

Comment: I got the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9589815/3603374).

Answer (score 1):

[MysqlWorkbench](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjw_4-bgMrLAhVFwxQKHS_uCnsQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysql.com%2Fproducts%2Fworkbench%2F&usg=AFQjCNFJK9_hOoitSDYCpqEnyvS9HSuh0A&sig2=FvWh9Dlpy1JPypnE_31VUw)

Or you could try [Toad for Mysql](http://software.dell.com/products/toad-for-mysql/)

Both are free and in both you can see either data or schema details, modifying either in a tabular interface. MySqlWorkbench has a modeling interface which may meet the graphical requirement that you are wanting. My preference is MySqlWorkbench. If you are writing queries and not a Sql scripting flyer you might find Toad more friendly but I dont think there are the modeling aspects.
Good Luck.